# openCV java binding does not generate VideoWriter class

Tags: java, opencv

I have a problem with openCV java binding. The problem is the VideoWriter class is not generated. I am using openCV 2.7.4.2  with windows 7  x64. any help ? thanks

Comment: Hello, can you please detail your question more? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, did you find solution, I also have the same problem which I cannot write video in OpenCV3

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a bug [check here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3453). Its missing in opencv java till date.